# Session Variable showing undefined

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, session, ionic-framework

I have made the login page using ionic and it seems to work well. The $_SESSION variable also gets displayed after successfull login. Then in another php file, when I try to print the same session variable, it shows undefined or not set. Also, the session expires after refresh and it shows an alert to login again

```
Here is my login php code

    <?php
ob_start();
session_start(); 
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

$errors = array();
$data = array();

// Getting posted data and decodeing json
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

require_once 'db_functions.php';
$db = new db_functions();


if(empty($_POST['doc_key']))
{
  $data['errors'] = 'Please enter all the credentials';
  echo json_encode($data);
}
else if(empty($_POST['password']))
{
  $data['errors'] = 'Please enter all the credentials';
  echo json_encode($data);
}
else
{    
    $doc_key = $_POST['doc_key'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $user = $db->getDoctorByEmailAndPassword($doc_key, $password);
    if( $user == true)
    {
        //session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['name'] = $user["name"];
        $_SESSION['contact'] = $user["contact"];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $user["email"];
        $_SESSION['license_no'] = $user["license_no"];
        $_SESSION['type'] = $user["type"];
        $_SESSION['gender'] = $user["gender"];
        $_SESSION['location'] = $user["location"];
        $_SESSION['fees'] = $user["fees"];
        $_SESSION['experience'] = $user["experience"];
        $_SESSION['doc_key'] = $user["doc_key"];
        //session_write_close();
        $data['message'] = $_SESSION['name'];// "User logged in successfully";
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    else
    {
      $data['errors'] = 'Login Credentials are invalid';
      echo json_encode($data);    
    }
}
?>
```

This is the code of other page where I want to display the session variable

```
    <?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:{$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }
$data = array();
$type_user = "";
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name']) || isset($_SESSION['license_no']))
{   
    if($type_user == "doctor")
    {
        $data["name"] = $_SESSION["name"];
        $data["email"] = $_SESSION["email"];
        $data["contact"] = $_SESSION["contact"];
        $data["license_no"] = $_SESSION["license_no"];
        $data["doc_key"] = $_SESSION["doc_key"];
        $data["gender"] = $_SESSION["gender"];
        $data["type"] = $_SESSION["type"];
        $data["location"] = $_SESSION["location"];
        $data["fees"] = $_SESSION["fees"];
        $data["experience"] = $_SESSION["experience"];
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else
    {
        $data["name"] = $_SESSION["name"];
        $data["email"] = $_SESSION["email"];
        $data["contact"] = $_SESSION["contact"];
        $data["gender"] = $_SESSION["gender"];
        $data["user_name"] = $_SESSION["user_name"];
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

}
else
{
    $data["errors"] = "Please login first to see this";
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

This page does not return the session data to controller. It shows blank
Here are the codes of controllers and ionic code

Controller for login page

```
.controller('doctorloginCtrl', function($scope,$http,$window) {
    $scope.doctor = {};
    $scope.loginDoc = function(){
        $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/drmedic/login_doctor.php',
        data: $scope.doctor,
        headers: {'ContentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
        .success(function(data){
            if(data.errors)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data.errors));
            }
            else
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data.message));
                $window.location.href = "#/home";
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Controller for the other page where I want to show the details

```
.controller('profileCtrl', function($scope,$http,$ionicSideMenuDelegate,$window) {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost/drmedic/retrieve_login_details.php'}).success(function(data) {
        if(data.errors)
        {
            alert(data.errors);
            $window.location.href = "#/select-role";
        }
        else
        {       
        $scope.contents = data;
        console.log($scope.contents);
        }
    });

})
```

After login, when I go to the profile page by typing localhost:8100/#profile, it shows blank.. It does not display the {{contents.name}} field

IONIC CODE for Profile page

```
<ion-view title="Profile">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" scroll="false" class="has-header">
        Hi {{contents.name}}
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The sessions used to work properly for my other project. Can't figure it out why it isn't working for this one. Is it because of the Authentication-Allow-Cross headers??

Please help.

Comment: Perhaps the session is not saving. What driver are you using for php sessions? If it's the default, it will be in files, perhaps php doesn't have permissions to open a file? Have you got all error reporting turned on? Another possibility is that your session cookie is getting unset somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris.. The error_reporting was not set to 0 and nor was there any error in the code.

Comment: One of my friend told me that sessions cannot be used with ionic as ionic treats the php pages as API's when they are used for data retrieval or for sending data. So, in that case I cannot use sessions. Instead, I will have to use $rootScope in angular to save the user details after login and then the value in $rootScope can be accessed in any controller and can be displayed in the page associated with the controller.

Comment: I tried doing that and it worked. Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript localStorage Property. It will store data in your device until you remove it. So this is very easy to keep some data in the device. You can acccess it from anywhere in your code if it is exists.

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

for more information visit https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp